# My connection class doesn't read inputs values?

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle, class, database-connection

I have below classes and one mainForm. I want to get user login inputs and connect my oracle database. But when I track in debugging mode user inputs not assigned to getters and setters so, when I called my helper class to connect database null values passing to my connection string inside my connection class... and I can not access to my database. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't set any values.

This:

```
AccessorClass s = new AccessorClass();

... = ConnectionClass.Connection(s.DB, s.ID, s.Password);
                                //  ^^   ^^    ^^^^^^^^^ - no values in these
```

Use an initialization list to set them:

```
AccessorClass s = new AccessorClass() { DB = "Database", ID = "ID", Password = "Password" };
```

EDIT:

Your update won't work either. You're creating an `AccessorClass` object, then calling a method. In that method.. you're `new`'ing up another `AccessorClass`. Do this:

```
AccessorClass s = new AccessorClass ();    
s.DB = txtDatabase.Text;
s.ID = txtID.Text;
s.Password = txtPassword.Text;

HelperClass.Get(s); // <--- pass the instance through
```

Then change your `HelperClass.Get` function to this:

```
public static void Get(AccessorClass s)
    {
        // REMOVED: AccessorClass s = new AccessorClass();              

        OracleConnection conn = ConnectionClass.Connection(s.DB, s.ID, s.Password);
```

Comment: Can you please more clear... DB = "Database", ID = "ID", Password = "Password"

Comment: Those are your properties on the `AccessorClass` object. Doing that sets their values at the time you declare it.

Comment: sorry I edit my questions...Please see my MainForm I am getting values from my textBoxes...

Comment: didnt Work! getting the values from user input

Comment: Why I can't get table names inside my List<>...in Helper class?